# Magento 2: Can't save product after I edit it

Tags: magento2, product

If I try to edit a product, when I click Save, I get the spinning GIF and 'Please wait..." forever... The only way I can get out of it is to refresh my browser, which cancels and loses my edits.

Anyone else encountered this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it! Seems to be something to do with my browser's cache (Firefox). I tried to update the same product using Safari and it worked without any issues.